# INNER JOIN on same table counting word occurrences

Tags: mysql, inner-join

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e6382

```
id   id_news  word
 1    6       superman
 2    6       movie
 3    6       review
 4    6       excellent
 5    7       review
 6    7       guardians of the galaxy
 7    7       great
 8    8       review
 9    8       superman
10    8       movie
11    8       great
```

I have a small problem, I'm trying to relate different news through words with a threshold setting, in the example provided `id_news 6` should be related to `8` but not to `7` since `7` only has `2` words in common and I only want to detect those who have at least `3` words in common.

Answer (score 4):

This will get you close to what you need:

```
  SELECT wa1.id_news id, wa2.id_news related
    FROM word_analysis wa1
    JOIN word_analysis wa2
      ON wa2.id_news != wa1.id_news
     AND wa2.word = wa1.word
GROUP BY wa1.id_news, wa2.id_news
  HAVING COUNT(*)>2
ORDER BY wa1.id_news, wa2.id_news
```

If you don't want the reverse relationships:

```
  SELECT wa1.id_news id, wa2.id_news related
    FROM word_analysis wa1
    JOIN word_analysis wa2
      ON wa2.id_news > wa1.id_news
     AND wa2.word = wa1.word
GROUP BY wa1.id_news, wa2.id_news
  HAVING COUNT(*)>2
ORDER BY wa1.id_news, wa2.id_news
```

If you want to investigate just one `wa1.id_news` (6):

```
  SELECT wa2.id_news related
    FROM word_analysis wa1
    JOIN word_analysis wa2
      ON wa2.id_news != wa1.id_news
     AND wa2.word = wa1.word
   WHERE wa1.id_news = 6
GROUP BY wa1.id_news, wa2.id_news
  HAVING COUNT(*)>2
ORDER BY wa2.id_news
```

If you want to investigate just one relationship (6->8), where a result means related and no result means unrelated:

```
  SELECT 1
    FROM word_analysis wa1
    JOIN word_analysis wa2
      ON wa2.id_news = 8
     AND wa2.word = wa1.word
   WHERE wa1.id_news = 6
GROUP BY wa1.id_news, wa2.id_news
  HAVING COUNT(*)>2
```

Comment: Thank you so much to everyone of you :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this self-join:

```
SELECT
  wa1.id_news id_news_1,
  wa2.id_news id_news_2,
  count(wa2.word) cnt_words
FROM word_analysis wa1
INNER JOIN word_analysis wa2
ON wa1.id_news <> wa2.id_news AND wa1.word = wa2.word
GROUP BY wa1.id_news, wa2.id_news
HAVING count(wa2.word) >= 3
ORDER BY wa1.id_news, wa2.id_news;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e6382/24)</kbd>

Comment: Wonder if there's a way to narrow down the results from [8,6] and [6,8] to just one or the other.

Comment: @Matt yep, just use > or < instead of <> on the on clause.  However, this works for this set of data... but I'm not sure how this actually relates ID 6 and 8  It returns 2 records, but shouldn't it be 1 if it's a relationship? Furthermore, if multiple news stories have the same count how do you differentiate?  This is a good first start but I don't think it's the final answer.